# Coding autocorrelation function correctly in python

Tags: python, loops, autocorrelation

I have a two data sets, each of which are 325 elements long. One is data along and X-axis, one is data along the y-axis. Together, Q[0] and Q[1] make up Q.

The equation should be something like:

(Q(i+deltai,j) - mean(Q_i,j)) x (Q_i,j - mean(Q_i,j)) / (Q_i,j - mean(Q_i,j))^2

Which is an autocorrelation function. I want to iterate through i + delta i for the first function while looping through the data in Q. I did start to write two for loops for this, and then tried np.correlate. In the end, I think I got confused being new to python and felt like I spent the last few days chasing my tail.

The code I tried is:

```
I = npzfile['i']
Q = npzfile['q']
U = npzfile['u']

nxside = Q.shape[0]
nyside = Q.shape[1]

for i in numpy.arange(0,nxside-1,1):
     result = numpy.correlate(Q[0], Q, mode='full')
     result2 = (result/float(result.max()))
     plt.plot(result2, '-')

 for i in numpy.arange(0,nxside-1,1):
     for j in numpy.arange(0, nyside-1,1):

# #       # J= (i)
# #       # # L = ()
# #       # # print L
     M = (Q - numpy.mean(Q))
     B = (Q[i] - numpy.mean(Q))
     K = (Q - numpy.mean(Q))**2
     Z = numpy.abs(M*B)/numpy.abs(K)
#    print numpy.abs((M*B)/K)
     plt.plot(Z, 'ro')
```

I'd expect the output to be something that varies between 0 and 1 on the y-axis, over 325 elements.